# How to make a single Access form create multiple records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm relatively new in using Access.

I'm creating a database for questions and answers. Answers are stored in the answertable with the following fields: timestamp, question id, answer text, person id. Each record only contains one answer.

Now, I'm looking for a way that lets me update/enter multiple records at the same time. For instance, the person  using the form should be able to fill all respondent's answers, then hit submit. If there were five questions, the result should be five records with only the field 'answer text' differing from the other four.

I've searched on Stackoverflow but the only solutions that are given are in RoR. I'm experienced in VBA, but that's it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're describing a web HTML form interface, which is stateless and unbound. Access uses bound data that is stateful, so that design is completely unnecessary. You need to rethink the design in Access terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main form should be bound to the table that has one record per person.  On that form you can add a subform (default view datasheet) that is bound to the table that has one record per question.  You will want to set the link between the main form and the subform to be on person id.

Once you have the subform, you can hide the person id and question id fields.

Before you open the form, you will need to run a query to make sure that all the required questions that the person should answer are already added to the answer table, populating both person id and question id.

You may want to adjust the datasource of the subform to include the question text by linking to the table that is keyed on question id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if a question should have only one answer, and an answer should have olnly a question, why are they in different tables?

But, if your question table should have more than one answer, its ok.

You cannot edit multiple records in MS-Access in same time. You must to implement a form in GridView mode, wich will retrieve the desired questions, or allow user to add records on it. When user edits all the rows, the user should click a button wich will startup a process that will read the gridView and update the table, one by one.

The smartest way ought to be create a form in gridView mode, linking it to the answer table. Then filter the data presentagion on this form to fit in your desired params. When the user edits an answer presented, this row will be automatically updated in table.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with your fundamental UI question. One question and one answer on a form.